# Aren't $f(x)=\frac{2x}{x+8}$ and $ g(x)=\frac{2}{1+\frac{8}{x}}$ equivalent?

Tags: functions

Aren't these two functions
$$
f(x)=\frac{2x}{x+8}
$$

and
$$
g(x)=\frac{2}{1+\frac{8}{x}}
$$

supposed to be different in that $f(x)$ is not defined for $x=-8$ and $g(x)$ is not defined for $x=-8 \text{ and } 0$?

The desmos graphing calculator shows that $g(0)=0$ and I don't understand how. Clearly $f(x)$ cannot be written as $g(x)$ for $x=0$

Any idea as to what is going on in Desmos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, Desmos gives you the limitimg value (if that is defined) if it cannot produce the value at the exact point.

So, it puts a very small real number into $g(x)$, ant finds a very small real number, *which is equal to $0$ for a programmed software*.

Comment: Desmos simply outputs the value as 'undefined' when it encounters divide by zero situations.

Answer (score 4):

We can rewrite the $$g(x) = \frac{2}{1+\frac{8}{x}}$$
$$\text{into}$$
$$g(x) = \frac{2}{\frac{x+8}{x}}$$
$$g(x) = \frac{2x}{x+8}$$

We can see that $g(x) = f(x)$, however, keep in mind that when "refactoring" the $f$ into $g$ (or the other way around), we assumed that $x \neq 0$, therefore we cannot expect $g$ to behave in the same manner as $f$ in $x = 0$!

Comment: I arrived at $g(x)$ from $f(x)$

Comment: Yeah, consider it as "removing" the undefined values as we very often do when we are computing the limits that are in form $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: I know that part. My question though, is about Desmos' behaviour at $x=0$ for $g(x)$ for Desmos doesn't do algebraic simplification as far as I know.

Comment: But do you understand that when going from $f$ to $g$, you assumed that $x \neq 0$? Therefore $g$ is not "valid" equation with respect to $f$ and you cannot consider $g(0)$ as a valid form of expression

Comment: I have edited my answer to the extent that it should be crystal clear by now :) @AbhishekAUdupa

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, Desmos takes your definition of $g$ and silently converts it back to $f$ to make sense of $g(0)$.

Either way, when you divide by $x$, you are assuming $x\neq 0$.